# How to see the steps of calling javascript functions in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, firebug

I'm working with JVectorMap and I have made some changes on the code as well.
the program works well but I don't know why when I'm rendering the map two request for rendering the page send to my servlet.

everything seems ok and I didn't call my rendering servlet code twice but I don't know why two request come to my servlet.

I supposed that may be a refresh request while rendering, somewhere but I couldn't find any, I want to check the process of rendering my page step by step to figure out what the problem is but It seems debugging the javascript is a cumbersome task and I don't know how in firebug I can check each part of my code step by step as I have some javascript file imported as well.

do you have any suggestion or idea ?

Answer (score 0):

On the script tab of firebug click at the line where you want to stop execution.

Alternatively you could insert `debugger;` instruction in your code.

Then use buttons on the top of script tab. If you don't know how - google for "debugging javascript with firebug".

Comment: Dude I solved the problem already !
I know how to debug using firebug better than those tutorials, my case was different, I wanted to go over each part & check the process runtime while there are different javascript file involve.
anyways thank you, I solved the problem already !